# dynamic url where text box data changes url

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

here is what i have. a sharepoint page that has a textbox and a search button. the textbox data is tied to all of my tables and fills them in according to the company code typed into the textbox.

i'm trying to add a url that will also take the user out to a new page where they will see a sharepoint list filtered on the company code they entered in the original textbox.

so far i can make the url go to whatever company i choose by hardcoding the url like this:

```
http://mysite/Lists/Call%20Log/Company%20by%20Category.aspx?View={7C16BC72-8F1A-457A-9908-AF9E66DE97DC}&FilterField1=LinkTitle&FilterValue1=abccompany
```

for whatever reason i am unable to or can't figure out how to set `filtervalue1 = <<text from textbox>>`.

here is a sample of the code:

```
<WebPartPages:SPProxyWebPartManager runat="server" id="ProxyWebPartManager">
</WebPartPages:SPProxyWebPartManager>
Enter the CO ID and click &quot;Search&quot;&nbsp;
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="tb_coID" Width="83px"></asp:TextBox>
&nbsp;
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Search" id="Button1"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a target="_blank" href="http://site/Lists/Call%20Log/Company%20by%20Category.aspx?View={7C16BC72-8F1A-457A-9908-AF9E66DE97DC}&amp;FilterField1=LinkTitle&amp;FilterValue1=<<text from textbox here>>">
Click Here </a>to view Call Logs
```

Comment: Show us the code where you are attempting to set the filterValue to the textbox.

Comment: i'm making it in sharepoint designer so everything has been done in design mode. Should I post the actual code for the whole page?

Comment: here is the code showing my textbox and the hyperlink:

    </WebPartPages:SPProxyWebPartManager>Enter the CO ID and click &quot;Search&quot;&nbsp;
 <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="tb_coID" Width="83px"></asp:TextBox>
 &nbsp;
 <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Search" id="Button1"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
 <a target="_blank" href="http://site/Lists/Call%20Log/Company%20by%20Category.aspx?View={7C16BC72-8F1A-457A-9908-AF9E66DE97DC}&amp;FilterField1=LinkTitle&amp;FilterValue1=***this where i need the text from the text box to populate***">
 Click Here </a>to view Call Logs<br>
 <br>

Comment: Post it on the question, not as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in case anyeone else is looking this is the answer to my question that i figured out.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showReport() {
var coid = document.getElementById('ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_tb_coID').value;
window.open("http://site/Lists/Call%20Log/Company%20by%20Category.aspx?View=     {7C16BC72-8F1A-457A-9908-AF9E66DE97DC}&amp;FilterField1=LinkTitle&amp;FilterValue1=" +     coid, "_blank");
}
</script>
    <WebPartPages:SPProxyWebPartManager runat="server" id="ProxyWebPartManager">
    </WebPartPages:SPProxyWebPartManager>Enter the CO ID and click     &quot;Search&quot;&nbsp;
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="tb_coID" Width="83px"></asp:TextBox>
    &nbsp;
    <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Search" id="Button1"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&    nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="showReport();">Click Here</a> to view     Call Logs related to this Company<br>
    <br>
```

i just had to add these lines of code to the top of my page and it works amazingly